# Copy command prompt text to a notepad file

Tags: cucumber

I am trying to create a framework for Cucumber with Ruby. I am running cucumber from the command prompt. I want to know how I can copy the step definitions created by cucumber in the command prompt to a ruby file, that I should create.

Comment: I am clueless as to how I can do dis.. I am stuck... I have executed a feature file using cucumber...

Answer (score 0):

You should be all to copy the "stub" steps created when you ran cucumber into a new Ruby file, and name it with "_steps.rb" as the end of the file name.  So long as that new file is stored within the same directory hierarchy as your feature file, when you re-run cucumber, it should see those new steps.

So for example, if your feature file is:

mytest.feature

...when you run cucumber, copy the stub steps that display into a file called:

mytest_steps.rb

(It's good practice to place steps files in a "step_definitions" sub-folder underneath the folder that contains your feature files).

Then when you run "cucumber mytest.feature", your new steps should be found.  They'll still be treated as pending steps until you add some real code to flesh out each step, but this should at least get you started!